# FB like count doesn't work in code igniter framework

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-like

I really need help on solving our FB like bug.

So when we created new products/article, FB like count status was still 0, but when someone hit like, it automatically jumped to 1.6k.
When I checked, it's actually not the article that's being read but it's actually the root domain.

Please see the image after you click like

So instead of the root url, it should've been

While in the script property. Href-data already used URL for the particular article.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?=current_url();?>" data-width="1" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
```

I also have tried data-href with other page, for example:

And it's also the same case, once I hit like, it's liking the root url instead of the actual link

Then I changed the data-href using the other url like

[www.cnn.com/2013/10/04/politics/government-shutdown-main/index.html?hpt=hp_t1][6]

it works very well. what's liked it's actually that article not in our site

But strangely if changed it using our subdomain =

The like can go to the right url

This brought into conclusion. when data-href is pointed to page/article from our site, since it's using Code igniter, then like button doesn't point to the right page/article.

Perhaps there's problem inside CI setting  that causes this, I need to find out where this is. Perhaps you could help!
If it's pointed to
this would work because store is not developed using CI and it's a separate entity than our site . Again this is just the conclusion after several tests that I did, you might have different opinion.

Please let me know what to do to get around this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is `current_url()` ? if you echo it what is the output?

Comment: the resutl would be the article url. not the root url. in that sense is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>`

Like:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" data-width="1" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
```

Have you included **JavaScript SDK** in your page?

**UPDATE**:
Try to add meta property tags in your header like:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/>
```

And.or others too. The complete list can be found e.g. here: http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: Thank you derfder. try to open https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works. if you check on FB manual, it doesn't need javascript sdk because if linking to outside nzxt, it works.. so this is not javascript SDK problem. I think the problem is for sure lies in NZXT engine. because I checked directly using facebook tools, it still won't do it. the like result is to root domain not article.. you could try it on developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button Just try it there

This is directly inside facebook developer tools, and this is why I think the problem is inside the code igniter setting. Perhaps you have other idea? thanks
Where inside code igniter to make the like setting to not goes to root url but to the actual article URL?  I tried it test.php outside codeigniter frameworks and it works.
So this is obvious the problem is inside code igniter setting.

I've solved this problem by without using canonical and og::url